# SWIG-generated C++ wrapper causes many compilation errors

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap one class in a large C++ codebase for python using SWIG, and am having some problems compiling the generated C++ wrapper.

I created a basic interface file, PCSearchResult.i:

```
%module PCSearchResult
%{
 #include "PCSearchResult.h"
%}
%include "PCSearchResult.h"
```

I generated PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx with:

```
swig -c++ -python PCSearchResult.i
```

And tried to compile using:

```
g++ -c -fpic -I. -I$(OTHERINCS) -I/usr/include/python2.7 PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx
```

This results in a huge number of errors. Here are the first 15 lines:

```
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_new_PCSearchResult__SWIG_1(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3226:3: error: 'Point3d' was not declared in this scope
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3226:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from PointCloud.h:28:0,
                 from PCSearchResult.h:29,
                 from PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3044:
Point3d.h:43:7: note:   'Isis::Point3d' 
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3226:12: error: 'arg1' was not declared in this scope
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3230:19: error: 'PointCloud' was not declared in this scope
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3230:19: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from PCSearchResult.h:29:0,
                 from PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3044:
PointCloud.h:80:7: note:   'Isis::PointCloud'
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3230:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
PCSearchResult_wrap.cxx:3230:38: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
```

All of the "not declared in this scope" errors make me think that I must be failing to include something in the correct place. I know I have the all the correct header files #included in PCSearchResult.h, since everything compiles and runs well when not using SWIG.

Is there somewhere else I need to give SWIG information about classes I'm using in the header file I'm trying to wrap (which are defined in other header files)? I have read the [SWIG and C++ chapter](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus) of the SWIG documentation and am still confused about this.

I'm using SWIG version 3.0.2 and g++ version 4.7.2 on Fedora 18.

Comment: You should post your code here as well. This might not be enough to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Point3d is in a namespace. In your own source files you probably use the full decl or you have a using namespace decl in the source. So try adding a `using namespace Isis;` in the .i file:

```
%module PCSearchResult
%{
#include "PCSearchResult.h"
using namespace Isis;
%}
%include "PCSearchResult.h"
```

This will insert it in the wrap.cxx file.